# Are python functions threadsafe? (Particularly this one?)

Tags: python, multithreading, scope

Before answering, please understand I do NOT want you to do the work for me.  I would rather appreciate a worded answer as to why my (possibly theoretical) problem exists, and an explanation of the process to go about fixing it.  I find it harder to learn properly when someone just does the work for me.  Thank you in advance.

I have this function:  It does exactly what it looks like it's doing.  It is using the html from a page which contains a facebook ID and returning the ID once found.

```
def getID(data): #Find an ID from HTML input.
    data = str(data)
    appstring = 'http://apps.facebook.com/castle_age/keep.php?user=' #We're gonna find this in the html.
    appstr_start_pos = data.find(appstring) #Tell us where we found it oh mighty one!
    if appstr_start_pos != -1: #If we find it.
        begin_ID_pos = appstr_start_pos + len(appstring)
        end_ID_pos = data.find('"', begin_ID_pos) #Find the end quote, that'll be the end of our ID string.

        our_ID = data[begin_ID_pos:end_ID_pos]
        return our_ID
```

Right now I do not have it packaged in one of my classes which uses the thread.Threading method, but I am still calling it regularly.  My code right now is only running one thread, and it's possible that I might need to call this function from another threaded class; is this possible?  If not, how can I use this function between threaded classes?

A more simple form of the question:  If I call this function from a multi-threaded environment, will I have problems, or do I need to move it into its own class?  Is there a way to keep the function available between 2 different threaded objects (if so what's the easiest way)?

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/txH8PvL3 -- Please keep in mind that it is a WIP, as practice for learning threading...

Comment: "Understanding the Python GIL" http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf describes (among other things) how python threads work

Comment: I've read a lot about the GIL lately, especially davids work with priority-threads in order to work around the CPU/IO bound problems when you have one thread IO-bound and another CPU-bound in the Python 3.2 GIL.  But, when python calls a function...does it make a COPY of that function? (So if the function (as long as it wasn't modifying some scope above the function) is called, it wouldn't clash with another thread calling it at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A more simple form of the question: If I call this function from a multi-threaded environment, will I have problems,

Yes it is thread-safe from what I can tell

> or do I need to move it into its own class?

Thread safety has nothing to do with classes: it has to do with shared state.  If threads share state, provisions must be made to access/mutate this state in a thread-safe manner i.e. using locks.

Comment: +1: The function seems to merely fetch things and not update anything.  If another function is updating `data` concurrently, then you will have thread safety issues.

Comment: So just to clarify, if I had 2 threads call getID (at the same time), and they both passed in their own separate string objects, this would not fail?

Comment: @Thantik: correct.  The function isn't mutating any shared state.

Comment: @ThantiK:  The point is that there's no mutation of the `data` item.  Whether or not you have two separate string objects doesn't matter.  Two threads could both use the same string object, since no mutation is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Builtin functions `len()`, `str()` that is used in your function can be monkey-patched in other threads.

Comment: I don't anyone needs to be concerned about *data*. Either it's a mutable object, in which case it's string representation is being returned by data.__str__(), which creates a new object, or *data* is already a string, which is still cool because Python strings are immutable. So it doesn't matter if another thread modifies data, it should have no side effects in getID().

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy because every `get*()` function could use caches.
So every call could leat into data changes. -> problem